# Ribbon customization, always have access to a sheet

Tags: user-interface, ribbon, worksheet

Hello competent people out there!

I have made a time registration sheet, that I use at my work place, in which I type in the hours that I am working on which assignment etc. Every time I need to use this sheet I find its physical location on the hard drive and open it. Through all day this sheet is open because I continuously has to registrate what I do. I want to get rid of this process.

My question now is: is there a good way to "put" this sheet up into the ribbon, so that I can access it from any excel workbook that I am working in? My first thought has been to add a button that simply opens up the workbook, but that wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I want to integrate this "time registration" into Excel itself.

Any input will be helpful.

Thank you very much!